# Adding a secondary axis in the chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am generating a chart from the data available in my pivot table.

I would like to generate a column chart from a pivot table.

The pivot table has percentage values and absolute numbers. I have the percentage values in column D and E, and absolute numbers in column B and C. I would like to have a secondary y-axis for my chart with percentages. Can anyone tell me how I can proceed with this?

I have proceeded with the code as shown below.

```
Sub charts ()
Dim cht As Chart
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status").ChartObjects.delete
If ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
Set ptable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Set ptr = ptable.TableRange1
Set Sh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=1, _
    Width:=390, _
    Top:=100, _
    Height:=250)
Sh.Select
Set cht = ActiveChart
With cht
.SetSourceData ptr
.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

End With
'cht.SeriesCollection(2).Axes(xlValues, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 10
cht.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
cht.SeriesCollection(2).HasDataLabels = True
cht.SeriesCollection(3).HasDataLabels = True
cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) '<~~ Red
cht.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
cht.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
cht.HasTitle = True
cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Status"
End Sub
```

any lead would be helpful

Comment: Have you recorded a macro in which you add the secondary axis? This will (depending on the Excel version) produce code that you can explore and borrow from.

Comment: cht.SeriesCollection(3).AxisGroup = 2

Answer (score 2):

Add this code after you set the `cht` object:

```
With cht
    .HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True ' add the secondary axis
    .Axes(xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%" ' format it to percentage
End With
```

---

**Edit 1**: for future posts, use this code (it's yours) as it's not using any `ActiveSheet`, `Select`, `ActiveChart` or `Selection`.

Also, try to always use `Option Explicit` and define all your variables and objects in advance.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub charts()

Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim PvtRng As Range

' first set the sheet object
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify to your sheet's name

If Sht.PivotTables.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

' set the Pivot Table
Set PvtTbl = Sht.PivotTables(1)

' set the Range of the Chart (from the Pivot Table's range)
Set PvtRng = PvtTbl.TableRange1

' set the Chart Object
Set ChtObj = Sht.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=1, Width:=390, _
                            Top:=100, Height:=250)

' modify the Chart Object's properties
With ChtObj.Chart
    .SetSourceData PvtRng
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered

    'cht.SeriesCollection(2).Axes(xlValues, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 10

    ' add series to chart and format them
    .SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
    .SeriesCollection(2).HasDataLabels = True
    .SeriesCollection(3).HasDataLabels = True
    .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) '<~~ Red
    .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)

    ' add title
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Status"

    ' add a secondary axis, and format it
    .HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True ' add the secondary axis
    .Axes(xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%" ' format it to percentage
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I used the same code, this modified my primary Y-axis to percentage ,and no secondary axis is added

Comment: could you help me ?

Comment: Use the other submission. You need to assign one or more series to the secondary axis group before adding the axis, and in fact, the secondary value axis is usually added by default as soon as any series is assigned to the secondary axis group.

Answer (score 1):

seriescollections of d,e column ar to be grouped  by AxisGroup = 2 .

```
Sub charts()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim ptable As PivotTable
Dim ptr As Range
Dim Sh As ChartObject
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status").ChartObjects.delete
If ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
Set ptable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Set ptr = ptable.TableRange1
Set Sh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=1, _
    Width:=390, _
    Top:=100, _
    Height:=250)

Set cht = Sh.Chart
With cht
.SetSourceData ptr
.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

End With
'cht.SeriesCollection(2).Axes(xlValues, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 10
cht.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
cht.SeriesCollection(2).HasDataLabels = True
'cht.SeriesCollection(3).HasDataLabels = True

cht.SeriesCollection(3).AxisGroup = 2
cht.SeriesCollection(4).AxisGroup = 2
cht.SeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlLine
cht.SeriesCollection(4).ChartType = xlLine

cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) '<~~ Red
cht.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
cht.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
cht.SeriesCollection(4).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(110, 110, 255)

cht.HasTitle = True
cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Status"
cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"
End Sub
```